# Influxdb 2.0 Backup Fails with Read:authorizations is unauthorized

Tags: backup, bolt, influxdb-2

I am trying to backup influxdb using backup command as stated in v2.0 doc.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/backup-restore/backup/

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.0
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    volumes:
      - influxdb-data:/var/lib/influxdb2
      - /influxdb-backup/:/influxdb-backup/
    restart: always

volumes:
  influxdb-data:
    external: true
```

The Backup Commmand fails as follow.

```
docker-compose exec influxdb influx backup influxdb-backup -t xxx 
2021-04-22T22:14:06.631863Z info    Backing up KV store {"log_id": "0TfvCY9G000", "path": "20210422T221406Z.bolt"} 
Error: Read:authorizations is unauthorized. 
See 'influx backup -h' for help
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a soloution by any chance ?

Comment: I had to recreate the service and it worked. I was migrating from older influxdb version causing this error.